# I use ubuntu with lubuntu-desktop, do I dare upgrade ubuntu?

Tags: upgrade, lubuntu

I use ubuntu, but I had problems with Unity, so I changed to use lubuntu-desktop:

```
sudo apt-get install lubuntu-desktop
```

The updating manager is now saying that there is a new version of ubuntu, and asks if I want to upgrade. Can I safely do that without getting problems with my desktop, or Unity coming back and replacing it?

Edit: I am currently running Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS, and the update manager asks me to upgrade to 14.04.1 LTS. It would be interesting to know the answer to my question for this particular upgrade, but also generally.

Comment: you can never be 100% sure that you will not get any problems.

Comment: @Private: true, but maybe someone has already tried upgrading with a similar setup and can report how it went. :)

Comment: What version are you upgrading to? and from?

Comment: Updated original post

Answer (score 2):

Since you only installed Lubuntu-desktop on top of Ubuntu, it is still there with all of its applications.  Unless you uninstall it, it will always be there.  You must do something because Lubuntu 12.04 has reached its End of Life and is no longer supported.  By upgrading you will get Ubuntu 14.04 with all of its applications as well as Lubuntu 14.04.  If that is not what you want you should do a fresh install of Lubuntu 14.04.  Before you do either, you should back up all your data because you never know what can happen and if there is something that you do not want to lose, it could happen.  Though there have probably been tens of thousands of successful distribution upgrades, I am 0 for 3 and I did back up my data so I didn't lose a thing.

Comment: Does Lubuntu 12.04 reaching EOL actually mean that the `lubuntu-desktop` package in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS is no longer supported?

Comment: It means that the Lubuntu portion will no longer receive security updates and bug fixes.  Ubuntu 12.04 is a long term support version and it will continue to be supported.

Comment: Cool, I'll give it a go then. :)